# Can't find again some pages about theory of screws - Schraubentheorie

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, reference-request

Some weeks ago i found some pages about a theory of screws of Sir Robert Ball - Schraubentheorie. It was an introduction and there were about two paragraphs that describe mainly the definitions of the geometrical objects of the theory e.g. Schraubentheorie ( theory of screws ) and translations in french and italian languages. I think it was a publication written in german language and the year of publication could be between 1930 and 1950.

The most important page was divided in two parts at about the center of the page itself, the upper with the main text and the lower with a smaller text notes connected with the upper by note numbers. The titles of the paragraphs were written in bold and with parenthesis with inclined text inside (the translation probably in english). The main paragraph could have its title beginning with "§.8". The publication was freely readable online.

I forgot to bookmark it and have lost the pages.
Does anyone know the title of the publication or have an idea on how to find it again ?

Comment: Was there something you recollet/ found more interesting in it  than what is genenerally found other European languages? Is sci.math. mathematik still active?

Comment: If you need Ball's original "Theory of screws", it is available on [Archive.org](https://archive.org/search.php?query=robert%20ball%20screws). Otherwise I found [this article by F. Klein](https://zenodo.org/record/2360813#.Ybr7CS2h0SI), but it's in German only.

Comment: @Narasimham it was interesting because summing up the main ideas with links to books and papers, but especially because there is a complete reference of the terminology in several languages altogether.

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca I have seen these publications and they are very interesting but this one was important because there is a complete reference of the terminology in several languages altogether.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca: Thank you. Nowadays we are bit impatent .. looking for some  quick twisted 3d image effects!